# Prevent showing movie files after packaging unreal game

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, game-engine, packaging, unreal-engine4

I developed a game which has some videos inside it. I added videos into my project folder so that I can access them.

After packaging, on the folder all videos will be shown as its original format which everyone can play it.

How is it possible on release version no one can go to game folder and play it? Maybe some kind of encryption or change format of file which only its game can play it would help it.

For example when you have a game on your computer, the only way to see the video is that you play the game and you will see relevant videos in the right time. However, after packaging, all videos will be on a folder any everyone can go to the folder and play it and see videos even without playing game.

**Update:**

In Unity after releasing the game, you can't access assets, it will be shown in a file with `.resource` extension so no one can access it. However, in Unreal Engine, it will show the real file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have "Use PAK file" checked in Edit > Project Settings > Packaging.

To address your update, people can still access assets in .resource and .pak files, they are just containers, and even if you encrypt them they can just disassemble your game and find the key. There is no way you can stop a user accessing a file in your game.